# Get values from Dropdown list MVC values

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, dropdown, model-binding

I'm using the following piece of code to get a list of values.

```
using (var client = new PowerBIClient(new Uri(ApiUrl), tokenCredentials))
            {
                var groups = await client.Groups.GetGroupsAsync();

                List<PowerBIGroups> groupList = new List<PowerBIGroups>();
                foreach (var group in groups.Value)
                {
                    groupList.Add(new PowerBIGroups() { Id = group.Id, Name = group.Name });
                }
                return View(groupList);
            }
```

And in the view at the top I'm declaring the model as:

```
@model IEnumerable<PowerBIEmbedded.Models.PowerBIGroups>
```

To get the values of the dropdown list:

```
 @Html.DropDownList("groupId", new SelectList(Model.Select(k => k.Name)), "-- Select Group --", new { @class = "form-control", onchange = @"var form = document.forms[0]; form.action= 'GetUser'; form.submit();" })
```

See here, I'm able to get the values of the list in a a dropdown.  But how do I get the value of Id associated with it, that I'm adding in the controller?  Also, how do I get the Id in the code behind?

Using this piece of code in the onChange event in the dropdown list:

```
onchange = @"var form = document.forms[0]; form.action= 'GetUser'; form.submit();" }  I'm able to invoke the GetUser method inside the controller with the parameters as the Name property.
```

**How can I get the value of Id here.**

One more issue associated with this is that I've to run the application from index.html where the GetUser method is invoked otherwise it is giving me a 404 not found error. 
**How can I fix this?**

Comment: Please specify programming language/framework you're using in tags